# Is there a ruby console equivalent to Swift/Obj-C/iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, debugging

One of the best ways for me to work with Ruby was handling data in real time. In the debugger, I could set new variables, assign them, and manipulate the code.

Is this possible in xCode's Swift/Obj-C? It seems when I try to instantiate new variables, they are never accessible. Perhaps my syntax is wrong?

```
>> po let my_numb = 5
>> po my_numb

error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'my_numb'
```

Comment: you can edit existing variables and interrogate data but you can't inject arbitrary code like that, what example situation are you trying to deal with, it seems like a playground may be what you're looking for

Comment: I agree with @Wain. If you just want to toy around with some code and see the outcome straight away playgrounds are an excellent way to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Swift, you can use the [Swift REPL](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=18), which is exactly like IRB for Ruby.

<strike>You'll need to install Swift separately from the Xcode tools. Instructions to do that can be found here: https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift</strike>. The Swift REPL is installed along with Xcode.

Comment: A fascinating. Does this work alongside a running app though? Can I use this with a debugger?

Comment: No, this is purely a [read-eval-print loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop). But the REPL can be started from inside the LLDB debugger as stated by @Sulthan.

Answer (score 2):

The (LLDB) debugger is not really a Swift REPL but you can create convenience variables there, however they have to be prefixed with `$`:

```
expr var $foo: Int = 10 
p $foo
```

Also see [Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585154/xcode-how-to-exit-lldb-swift-repl/28585961#28585961) about entering REPL from the debugger:

```
(lldb) repl                  // enter REPL
(lldb) let my_numb: Int = 10 // create Swift variable
(lldb) :                     // exit REPL
(lldb) p my_numb             // print variable

(Int) $R0 = 10
```

Comment: You can also enter the Swift REPL from within the debugger ([and return to lldb again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585154/xcode-how-to-exit-lldb-swift-repl/28585961#28585961)).