# xcode 11 C++ lldb hell

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb, xcode11, macos-catalina

Inane question :  MacOs Catalina / XCode 11.3/C++ 
I set breakpoints for debugging- [then figured out how to unset them thanks to you guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665744/xcode-remove-all-breakpoints) - but for some reason every time I run my code, XCode forces me into lldb (low level debugger).  There are no breakpoints set, there must be some way to stop this, I am just not certain how. I have tried [:quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585154/xcode-how-to-exit-lldb-swift-repl) and exit - it works for that specific session, but when I rerun the code lldb begins again.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Usually, when you are running a process under Xcode and it stops in the debugger, it will be because your process has done something interesting (hit a breakpoint, got a signal, crashed, etc...)  The actual reason for the stop is displayed on the RHS of the PC ribbon in the source view.  What does that say?

Comment: Thank you, that resolved it.  Warning on an && without proper parenthesis.  Really appreciate your response, thank you